# animation.FuncAnimation maps

Tags: python, animation, maps

I am sorry I can't understand how to put the arguments through the animation.FuncAnimation module no matter how many examples I use. 
And my task is quite simple, I have geophysical arrays (time,x,y).
All I want is to animate how a certain field changes over time. 
I guess my func argument should simply be my plotting function with changing index along the time axis. But it just doesn't happen.

```
field.shape
(12,912,1125)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(lon,lat)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
def animate(dset,i):
    ax[i] = plt.pcolormesh(X,Y,field_monthly[i].T)
    plt.colorbar()
    plt.set_cmap('viridis')
    return ax
i = np.arange(12)
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate(field_monthly,i), frames=12, 
                               interval=500,
                               repeat=False,
                               blit=False)
```

I know I have some fundamental leak in my logic, but can't find it.
The code above is 1 out of 50 ways I tried twist and turn functions and indices.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There were a few issues with your implementation.

- ax[i], you have just one axis, do not confuse subplots with time steps / frames
- use the keyword `fargs` to pass additional arguments
- def animate(i, ...) the first argument must be the `frame`
- calling the colorer inside the update instead of once in the beginning

Fixing those gives:

```py
from matplotlib import animation, pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

k, n, m = 12, 30, 50

field = np.random.random((k, n, m))
x, y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(n), np.arange(m))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.pcolormesh(x, y, field[0].T)
plt.colorbar()
plt.set_cmap('viridis')

def animate(i, field2):
    plt.cla()
    h = plt.pcolormesh(x, y, field[i].T)
    return h,

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig=fig, func=animate, fargs=(field,),
                               frames=k, nterval=500, repeat=False, blit=False)
```